# Formatting Excel Borders with .Net

Tags: excel, .netlink

I have various tables generated in a *Mathematica* application and need to export this to `MSExcel` formatted in a specific way.

The `Excel` formatting has to be generated by *Mathematica*. I am not familiar with `.Net` (or `.NetLink`), but after searching, found this very useful code by Chris Degnan.

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
PutIntoExcel[data_List, cell_String, file_String] :=
  Module[{rows, cols, excel, workbook, worksheet, srcRange},
  {rows, cols} = Dimensions[data];
  NetBlock[
  InstallNET[];
  excel = CreateCOMObject["Excel.Application"];
  If[! NETObjectQ[excel], Return[$Failed],
 excel[Visible] = True;
 workbook = excel@Workbooks@Add[];
 worksheet = workbook@Worksheets@Item[1];
 srcRange = worksheet@Range[cell]@Resize[rows, cols];
 srcRange@Value = data;
 srcRange@Interior@Color = 13959039;
 (* OLE colours from http://www.endprod.com/colors/ *)
 worksheet@Range["E5:F5"]@Font@Bold = True;
 worksheet@Range["E5:F5"]@Interior@Color = 61166;
 worksheet@Range["E6:E9"]@Font@Color = 255;
 (* Reset the numeric values to get the correct type *)
 worksheet@Range["E6:E9"]@Value = Rest[data[[All, 1]]];
 workbook@SaveAs[file];
 workbook@Close[False];
 excel@Quit[];
 ]];
 LoadNETType["System.GC"];
 GC`Collect[]];

data = {{"Year", "Cartoon"}, {1928, "Mickey Mouse"}, {1934,
    "Donald Duck"}, {1940, "Bugs Bunny"}, {1949, "Road Runner"}};
outputfile = "C:\\Temp\\demo.xlsx";
Quiet[DeleteFile[outputfile]];
PutIntoExcel[data, "E5", outputfile];

Print[Panel[TableForm[data, TableSpacing -> {2, 4}]]];
```

This explains in detail how to format colours, but I run into problems with borders.

This code does work:

```
worksheet@Range["B3:C4"]@Borders@Color = 255;
```

However, specifying specific parts of the border does not:

```
worksheet@Range["B3:C4"]@Borders[xlDiagonalDown]@Color = 255;
```

and I get this error:

> NET::nocomprop: No property named xlDiagonalDown exists for the given COM object.

Specifying the weight of the line like this:

```
worksheet@Range["B3:C4"]@Borders@Weight = xlThick;
```

gives a different error:

> NET::methodargs: Improper arguments supplied for method named Weight.

Can anyone suggest what may be wrong?

Then after exporting a fancy formatted table to `Excel`, I need to export an `Excel` formula into the formatted cells, to enable the `Excel` user to modify and play with their own input data.

Comment: I am getting the following error when running your code `"A .NET exception occurred: \
"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been \
thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> \
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Microsoft Excel cannot \
access the file 'C:\\ Temp \\ 534E8A50'. There are several possible \
reasons:"`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Excel VBA enumeration values cannot be accessed symbolically through COM.  We must use the corresponding numeric values found by consulting the [Microsoft Excel object model enumeration reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb259481(v=office.12).aspx).

The relevant enumerations in this case are [XlBordersIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835915.aspx) (xlDiagonalDown = 5) and [XlBorderWeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197515.aspx) (xlThick = 4).

Once we know the enumeration values, the code is straight-forward:

```
xlDiagonalDown = 5;
xlThick = 4;
borders = range@Borders@Item[xlDiagonalDown];
borders@Weight = xlThick;
```

**Side Note: Complications**

Take note of the use of `Item` in the `Borders@Item[xlDiagonalDown]` expression.  If we wrote simply `Borders[xlDiagonalDown]`, we would get an error message complaining that there is no such property.  The reason is that Mathematica models COM properties using definitions that hold their arguments.  `Borders` is a property, so a direct argument of `xlDiagonalDown` remains unevaluated and is interpreted as a (non-existent) subproperty name.  `Borders@Item`, on the other hand, is a method.  Method arguments are not held, so `xlDiagonalDown` gets evaluated to its numeric value.  It is possible to use the `Borders` property directly, albeit in ugly fashion:

```
With[{dd = xlDiagonalDown}, borders = range@Borders[dd]]
(* or *)
borders = range@Borders[#] &@ xlDiagonalDown
(* or *)
borders = range@Borders[5]
```

**Complete Example**

Here is a complete example, using `Item`:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];
LoadNETType["System.GC"];

$outputFile = "C:\\Temp\\demo.xlsx";
Quiet @ DeleteFile @ $outputFile;

NETBlock @ Module[{xl, book, sheet, range, borders, xlDiagonalDown, xlThick}
, xlDiagonalDown = 5
; xlThick = 4
; xl = CreateCOMObject["Excel.Application"]
; book = xl@Workbooks@Add[]
; sheet = book@Worksheets@Item[1];
; range = sheet@Range["B2:G6"]
; borders = range@Borders@Item[xlDiagonalDown]
; borders@Color = 255
; borders@Weight = xlThick
; book@SaveAs[$outputFile]
; book@Close[]
; xl@Quit[]
]

GC`Collect[];

SystemOpen @ $outputFile
(* DeleteFile @ $outputFile *)
```

[image: excel screenshot showing diagonal borders]

**Formulas**

Formulas can be written into spreadsheet cells using the [Range.Formula](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) property.  Such formulas must be expressed in Excel syntax.  Here is an example with a formula that uses relative cell references and computes the Fibonacci sequence:

```
NETBlock @ Module[{xl, book, sheet}
, xl = CreateCOMObject["Excel.Application"]
; book = xl@Workbooks@Add[]
; sheet = book@Worksheets@Item[1];
; sheet@Range["A1:A2"]@Formula = 1
; sheet@Range["A3:A20"]@Formula = "=A1+A2"
; book@SaveAs[$outputFile]
; book@Close[]
; xl@Quit[]
]    

GC`Collect[];

SystemOpen @ $outputFile
(* DeleteFile @ $outputFile *)
```

[image: screenshot showing Excel formulas]

Comment: (+1) What `borders@Color = 255` mean? Removing or changing this command does not change anything in my case (I use Excel 2003), the borders are black.

Comment: As I understand it, this sets the colour of the border and 255 is Red. OLE colours from http://www.endprod.com/colors/  I am using Excel 2010 and it works - unfortunately dont have a 2003 version to verify.

Comment: @WReach Thanks for detailed reply!  Any idea re the 2nd part of teh question - exporting excel style formulas to the same cells where we applied the borders?

Comment: See the new "Formulas" section.

Comment: @WReach Works like a charm for individual formulas, however trying this: `worksheet@
   Range["D1:E1"]@Formula = {"=H4/E4", "=K4/E4", "=N4/E4", 
    "=Q4/E4"}[[1 ;; 2]];` places formulas in cells but do not calculate them?

Comment: @BlueMac Sorry, I have no insight on that behaviour.  I just now tried to assign multiple formulas from an array using VBA directly inside Excel (2007, in my case).  It didn't work either, although it failed in a slightly different way from when I performed the operation through COM from Mathematica.  Perhaps formula array assignment is broken in Excel?

Comment: @WReach Just wanted to check if I was doing something stupid :-).  My workaround is to do this: `worksheet@Range[#[[1]]]@Formula = #[[2]]) & /@ 
 Transpose[{{"D1","E1","F1","G1"}, {"=H4/E4", "=K4/E4", "=N4/E4", "=Q4/E4"}}]`  And with the top row in order I use excel to copy it down with FillDown

Answer (score 2):

I suggest write code formatting borders as following avoiding using the `Enum` values directly.

```
LoadNETType["Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex"];    
LoadNETType["Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight"];

Scan[(range@Borders[#]@Weight = XlBorderWeight`xlThick)&,{NETObjectToExpression[XlBordersIndex`xlDiagonalDown]}];
```

and `ColorIndex` refers to this chart because of no finding color enum names, i.e.:

```
range@Interior@ColorIndex = 19;(*Light Yellow*)
```

[image]

**Update:** see more [on ColorIndex here](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm).